# How to find and update nested objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Given the nested objects below, how do I find each 'female' and update their salary by 10%?

```
var topSalary = {
    'Alex' : {salary: 2000, gender: 'male'},
    'John' : {salary: 1440, gender: 'male'},
    'Sarra' : {salary: 5187, gender: 'female'},
    'Philip' : {salary: 3309, gender: 'male'},
    'Anna' : {salary: 2304, gender: 'female'},
};
```

Comment: Kindly add some more details.  For example I would assume you are doing this in JS or TS?

Comment: SO isn't a *Please do my homework* site. You should do your own work. When you've made an effort to do so and run into difficulties, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question about that code and we'll try to help. If you can't get started at all, ask your instructor for help. You'll find you'll have much better experiences here if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works and what our expectations are before you begin posting.

Answer (score 2):

To edit the objects in place:

```js
var topSalary = {
    'Alex' : {salary: 2000, gender: 'male'},
    'John' : {salary: 1440, gender: 'male'},
    'Sarra' : {salary: 5187, gender: 'female'},
    'Philip' : {salary: 3309, gender: 'male'},
    'Anna' : {salary: 2304, gender: 'female'},
};

console.log("Before:", topSalary)

Object.entries(topSalary).forEach(([name, details]) => {
 if (details.gender === 'female') {
  details.salary += details.salary * .1
 }
})

console.log("After:", topSalary)
```

NOTE: Look into [maths in JavaScript](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-the-problem-javascript-maths-2119d85dad2a) as working out 10% might not be as accurate as you'd like.

**To break down what's happening...**

`Object.entries(topSalary)` will give you a 2 dimensional array of the keys and the values like:

```
[
  [ 'Alex', { salary: 2000, gender: 'male' } ],
  [ 'John', { salary: 1440, gender: 'male' } ],
  [ 'Sarra', { salary: 5187, gender: 'female' } ],
  [ 'Philip', { salary: 3309, gender: 'male' } ],
  [ 'Anna', { salary: 2304, gender: 'female' } ]
]
```

This 2D array is looped over with `forEach` and the key and value are destructured in the arguments list: `([name, details])`.

The non-destructured version would look like:

```
Object.entries(topSalary).forEach((entry) => {
    const name = entry[0]
    const details = entry[1]
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate staffWithGender element by element (for example, by using a for loop), check the gender on each, finally - update the salary if its 'female'

```js
var staffWithGender = {
    'Ivan' : {salary: 2000, gender: 'male'},
    'Andrey' : {salary: 1440, gender: 'male'},
    'Marina' : {salary: 5187, gender: 'female'},
    'Oleg' : {salary: 3309, gender: 'male'},
    'Anna' : {salary: 2304, gender: 'female'},
};

for (var i in staffWithGender)
  if (staffWithGender[i].gender=='female')
    staffWithGender[i].salary *= 1.1;

console.log(staffWithGender);
```

Comment: You've not provided any explanation of why this is a solution, or made any effort to pass any knowledge on to the OP or any future reader here. Dumping code with no other information is not an answer. This site is about creating a knowledge base, and you've not provided anything in support of that goal. What does your answer contribute toward knowledge other than teaching how to copy/paste someone else's work?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow highly recommends only answering [well-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) questions. This is pretty clearly not one of them. In addition, check out [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I think it's a fine answer. What I would like to know @BorisLipschitz is why did you changed the staff names?

Comment: @gunn, i didn't, i guess the OP did after i've alredy copy&pasted the test data. Edit, yes, he did, just looked at the OP edits. Not gonna change it, TBH, i kinda regret posting those 3 lines. KenWhite is right about SO not being a "do my homework" site, and those 3 lines definitely not worth this chain of comments for sure.

Comment: All - I've updated the question in an attempt as making it better.